# Google location with longitude and latitude link

Tags: google-maps, location, maps

My android app create google location link with longitude and latitude.
If i place it like this.
google.com/maps/@**(latitude)**,**(longitude)**,205m/data=!3m1!1e3
It shows the location in satellite view in browser.
But the location is not marked.Is there any way to make a link which will mark that GPS position we provide in link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query google maps using this URL syntax:

```
www.google.com/maps/?q=yourlatitude,yourlongitude
```